# Binding X and Y values from an Object to a Chart in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a UI display, which is displaying several data points on the screen in tiles.  If the user clicks a Tile, I want to open a new window and chart the last 60 data points of that field against time.  However, I'm trying to use MVVM methodology and I'm running into issues being able to dynamically bind my X and Y values to the chart.  Any help is appreciated.

My View Model:

```
public partial class MainViewChartVM : ObservableObject
{
    private const int N_RECORDS = 60;

    private DataProperty _currentChartItem;

    public enum DataProperty
    {
        AmbientTemp,
        RelativeHumidity,
        BarometricPressure,
        WindSpeed,
        WindDirection,
    }

    public MainViewChartVM(DataProperty currentChartItem)
    {
        _currentChartItem = currentChartItem;

        InitializeChart();
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _chartTitle;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _chartUnits;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Sample_Data> _currentDataSet;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _independentValuePath;
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _dependentValuePath;

    private void InitializeChart()
    {
        // Update button options

        // Update chart
        CurrentDataSet = new ObservableCollection<Sample_Data>(DataLogger.Instance.ReadLastNSamples(N_RECORDS));

        IndependentValuePath = nameof(Sample_Data.SampleTime);

        switch (_currentChartItem)
        {
            case DataProperty.AmbientTemp:
                ChartTitle = nameof(Sample_Data.AmbientTemp);
                DependentValuePath = nameof(Sample_Data.AmbientTemp);
                break;
            case DataProperty.RelativeHumidity:
                break;
            case DataProperty.BarometricPressure:
                break;
            case DataProperty.WindSpeed:
                break;
            case DataProperty.WindDirection:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<Window x:Class="Monitor.Views.Misc.MainViewChart"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Monitor.Views.Misc"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:Monitor.Properties"
        xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=DotNetProjects.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainViewChart" Height="600" Width="1024"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Background="{StaticResource Blue4}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource LabelScreenTitle}"/>
            <Button Focusable="False" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Style="{StaticResource NoHover}" Click="Button_Click">
                <iconPacks:Material Kind="Close" Width="50" Height="50"/>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <charting:Chart x:Name="MyChart" Background="#f8f8f8ff" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="0">
                <charting:Chart.Series>
                    <charting:LineSeries Title="Your Series Title"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentDataSet}"
                            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding IndependentValuePath}"
                            DependentValueBinding="{Binding DependentValuePath}">
                        <charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="charting:LineDataPoint">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </charting:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    </charting:LineSeries>
                </charting:Chart.Series>
                <charting:Chart.Axes>
                    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="{x:Static properties:Resources.Display_Time}"/>
                    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="{Binding ChartUnits}"/>
                </charting:Chart.Axes>
                <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="Control">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
            </charting:Chart>
            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding PreviousDataSetCommand}" Margin="1">
                    <iconPacks:Material Kind="ChevronUp" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                </Button>
                <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Rows="6" Margin="1">
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                    <Button Content="test" Margin="1" Style="{StaticResource NormalButton}"/>
                </UniformGrid>
                <Button Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding PreviousDataSetCommand}" Margin="1">
                    <iconPacks:Material Kind="ChevronDown" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get the following error when I try to chart a parameter:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value.'

Comment: Maybe it's important to understand the difference between a methodology and a design pattern. MVVM is a design pattern that can be implemented using methodologies.

Comment: That's a terrible question. You don't really describe  the problem. You don't mention the library you are using to plot your graphs. You don't show the data models. Nothing. I hope that you understand that your question nis impossible to answer as you are the only person here that knows all the details. Maybe this link can help you: [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Maybe consulting the documentation of the library can help you. Therre you will usually find examples. You could also start a Google search for examples. Creating a line series is usually the simplest and most common form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `IndependentValueBinding` and `DependentValueBinding` are not paths, but binding to the actual data properties. A good approach to handle what you are trying to do may be to create a view model for that `Sample_Data` object. Then you can pass in the data you want to display via the `DataProperty` parameter in the constructor.

Here is an example of what that could look like.

#### Sample_DataViewModel

```cs
    public class Sample_DataViewModel
    {
        public Sample_DataViewModel(Sample_Data dataModel, MainViewChartVM.DataProperty dataProperty)
        {
            DataModel = dataModel;
            _currentChartItem = dataProperty;
        }

        public double IndependentValue => DataModel.SampleTime;
        public double DependentValue
        {
            get
            {
                switch (_currentChartItem)
                {
                    case MainViewChartVM.DataProperty.AmbientTemp:
                        return DataModel.AmbientTemp;
                    case MainViewChartVM.DataProperty.RelativeHumidity:
                        return DataModel.RelativeHumidity;
                    // ToDo: build out the other options, returning zero for now
                    case MainViewChartVM.DataProperty.BarometricPressure:
                    case MainViewChartVM.DataProperty.WindSpeed:
                    case MainViewChartVM.DataProperty.WindDirection:
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        public Sample_Data DataModel { get; }
        public MainViewChartVM.DataProperty _currentChartItem { get; }
    }
```

#### MainViewChartVM

```
// ToDo: these are not needed
//[ObservableProperty]
//private string _independentValuePath;
//[ObservableProperty]
//private double _dependentValue;

private void InitializeChart()
{
    // this is the sample data I used for testing
    var mockData = new Sample_Data[]{
            new Sample_Data(0,0,4),
            new Sample_Data(1,1,3),
            new Sample_Data(1.5,2,2),
            new Sample_Data(1.6,3,3),
            new Sample_Data(2,4,1),
        };

    // Update chart
    CurrentDataSet = new ObservableCollection<Sample_DataViewModel>(
        mockData.Select(x => new Sample_DataViewModel(x, _currentChartItem)));

}
```

#### XAML Charting Bindings:

```xml
<charting:LineSeries Title="Your Series Title"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentDataSet}"
                        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding IndependentValue}"
                        DependentValueBinding="{Binding DependentValue}">
```

#### Results

You can view the generating code files here:
https://github.com/EvanGeer/StackOverflowAnswers/blob/master/StackOverflowAnswers.Revit/StackOverflowAnswers.App/ChartingExample.xaml.cs

Ambient Temp Mock Data:
[image]

Relative Humidity Mock Data:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this led me in the right direction and I see what I was doing wrong.